# how to used Xenocode Browser Sandbox Deploy run application via IE

Tags: xenocode

i have this application but how to use its?
and example for 7-zip can?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about checking out the [product documentation](http://www.xenocode.com/Products/Virtual-Application-Studio/Docs/webframe.html)?